# Disable touch on scroll, enable gestures on its subviews?

Tags: ios, swift

I have to disable scrolling on scrollview, so it can be scrolled only by software and not by the user.

```
scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

This scrollview has some views, and they have `TapGesture` on them, I enabled their interaction :

```
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
```

But it will not work unless I enable the interaction on the scroller.
Is there any other way to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `isUserInteractionEnabled` to disable scroll on your tableView. Use `isScrollEnabled` instead of `isUserInteractionEnabled` and you don't need to change anything of your view

```
scrollView?.isScrollEnabled = false;
```

If you set `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `false`, it will ignore touchs on subviews of `tableView`, doesn't matter `isUserInteractionEnabled` of the subview is `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Set `isScrollEnabled` to `false` instead of `userInteractionEnabled`.

```
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

**isScrollEnabled**

> If the value of this property is true , scrolling is enabled, and if
>   it is false , scrolling is disabled. The default is true. When
>   scrolling is disabled, the scroll view does not accept touch events;
>   it forwards them up the responder chain.